# ListView and FileChooser

Tags: java, listview, javafx, filechooser

I am having a trouble with ListView accepting content. here is the code so if someone could give me an advice:

```
  public void button1Action(){
    Main main=new Main();
    FileChooser fc=new FileChooser();
    fc.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:\\Users"));
    List<File>selectedFiles=fc.showOpenMultipleDialog(null);
    if(selectedFiles!=null){
       for(int i=0;i<selectedFiles.size();i++){
           main.lview.getItems().add(selectedFiles.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
       } 
    }else{
        System.out.println("File is not Valid");
    }
}
```

After i finish choosing files it the paths do not show on listview.

Edit: Even if i manually through the code add some string it doesn;t show anything
this is my Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
BorderPane root=new BorderPane();
ListView<String> lview=new ListView<String>();

 Button btn_load = new Button("Load");
Button btn_play = new Button("Play");
Button btn_stop = new Button("Stop");
Button btn_next = new Button("Next");
Button btn_previous = new Button("Previous");
Button btn_rewind = new Button("Rewind");
TextField tf_pesma=new TextField();
Slider slider=new Slider();
HBox hbox=new HBox();
HBox hbox1=new HBox();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Logic logic=new Logic();
    slider.setValue(50);
    slider.setMin(0);
    slider.setMax(100);
    slider.setMaxWidth(100);
    lview.setDisable(false);
    lview.setVisible(true);
    lview.setPrefWidth(800);

 btn_load.setOnAction(e->{
     logic.button1Action();
    });
 lview.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
     @Override
     public void handle(MouseEvent event){

     }
 });


    VBox floor = new VBox();
    floor.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10)); 
    floor.setSpacing(10);
    floor.getChildren().addAll(addInHBox(),addInHBox1());
    VBox right=new VBox();
    right.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    right.setSpacing(10);
    HBox button=new HBox();
    button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    button.getChildren().add(btn_load);
    right.getChildren().addAll(lview,button);
    root.setBottom(floor);
    root.setRight(right);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 580);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Music Player");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
public HBox addInHBox(){
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    hbox.setSpacing(10);
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(btn_play,btn_stop,btn_next,btn_previous,btn_rewind);
    return hbox;
}
public HBox addInHBox1(){
    hbox1.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
    hbox1.setSpacing(10);
    tf_pesma.setPrefWidth(700);
    hbox1.getChildren().addAll(tf_pesma,slider);
    return hbox1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new `Main` instance in `Logic` class. 
The `ListView` displayed on the screen is not owned by the new Main instance you created.

To get rid of this problem, access `lview` of Main that already exists.

```
// Add this in Main class
private void button1Action() {
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    fc.setInitialDirectory(new File("C:\\Users"));
    List<File> selectedFiles = fc.showOpenMultipleDialog(null);
    if (selectedFiles != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedFiles.size(); i++) {
            lview.getItems().add(selectedFiles.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("File is not Valid");
    }
}
```

And change the handler.

```
btn_load.setOnAction(e->{
    button1Action();
});
```

Comment: "*You are creating new `Main` instance in `Logic` class.*" Where do you see that he defines `Logic`?

Comment: Thanks, you resolved it,i should just let it in the same main class ass my listview

Comment: @user1803551 `Logic logic=new Logic();` and `logic.button1Action();` indicates that, and `Main main=new Main();` in button1Action.

Comment: Does anyone have idea how can i replace "\" with "\\" in my string of absolutepath, so that my player  could read that path

Comment: @Mapet `getAbsolutePath().replace("\\","\\\\")` replaces "\" with "\\". But I'm not sure that your player will be able to recognize the replaced path.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add elements directly into the ObservableList given by `main.lview.getItems()`.

I advise you to do something like:

```
if(selectedFiles!=null){
   List<String> lpaths = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i=0;i<selectedFiles.size();i++){
       lpaths.add(selectedFiles.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
   } 
   main.lview.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(lpaths))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for hint but still no change.I will keep looking

Comment: @Mapet When you say "After i finish choosing files it the paths do not show on listview.", is there really nothing inside the ListView, or only empty Strings?

Comment: Hem, otherwise, this is faster but not same result to do:
`if(selectedFiles!=null)
   main.lview.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(selectedFiles));`

Comment: there are nothing, not even an empty string.